# Expository papers for Feit–Thompson Theorem

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

[Feit–Thompson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem) states that every finite group of odd order is solvable.

Its proof is near 300 pages so it is definitely not an easy paper to read without a prior knowledge about the general methods that are used in the proof and a fairly detailed sketch of the proof strategy in the hand.

> What are examples of good expository papers for this theorem?

Comment: The proof consists of assuming that there's a non-abelian simple group of odd order and derive a contradiction, so I removed the (rare) "solvable-groups" tag, and added the generic "gr" tag.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for your edit. By expository paper I mean something that is accessible for non-group theory specialists. I'm a geometrist but I also like exploring the other disciplines of mathematics.

Comment: @DouglasZare Interesting post! It didn't come to my attention when I was typing this question title.